# Why aren't both "for loops" working?

Tags: python

```
import csv

def csv_reader(file_obj):      
    reader = csv.reader(file_obj)
    # for row in reader:
        # print(" ".join(row))

    reader_2 = csv.DictReader(file_obj, delimiter=",")
    for row_2 in reader_2:
        print(row_2)

csv_path = "data.csv"
with open(csv_path, "r") as f_obj:
    csv_reader(f_obj)
```

I can't figure out why the second "for loop" only prints any text if the first "for loop" is commented out.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. It helps us a lot if you format your code correctly - would you mind taking the time to make sure that the alignment is correct?

Comment: You should consider constructing a more informative title.

Comment: What part of the alignment is incorrect?

Comment: @Apero has apparently already fixed it for you. This was how the question was written originally https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/43129413/1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The CSV reader has already consumed your file.
Calling [`file_obj.seek(0)`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/file_seek.htm) before using it again should do the trick.

Alternatively, opening (and then closing) the file for each operation will also work.

Answer (score 2):

It's because you are passing the same file handler to both `csv` reader objects. Once you iterate over it once, you have to manually do `file_obj.seek(0)` for it to work as intended, or else it simply acts like an empty file.